# Slide Menu Javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, menu, slide

I've been trying to create a sliding menu with jQuery, but I've been getting errors on lines 5 and 6 - functions not defined. Can any one see what the problem is with my code?

```
 // jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
jQuery(function($) {
 "use strict";
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $nav_list = $('#nav_list');
        $menuLeft = $('.pushmenu-left');


        $nav_list.click(function () {
            $(this).toggleClass('active');
            $('.pushmenu-push').toggleClass('pushmenu-push-toright');
            $menuLeft.toggleClass('pushmenu-open');
        });
    });
});
```

Here's the HTML:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>DogHouse</title>


<script type="text/javascript" src="PushMenuJS.js"></script>

<link href="PushMenuCSS.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>

<body class="pushmenu-push">
    <nav class="pushmenu pushmenu-left">
         <h3>Menu</h3>    
    </nav>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="main">
            <section class="buttonset">
                <div id="nav_list">Menu</div>
                <!-- End Content -->
        </div>
        <!-- End Main -->
    </div>
    <!-- End Container -->
        </body>
</html>
```

And finally, here's the CSS

```
.pushmenu a {
    display: block;
}
.pushmenu-left {
    left: -240px;
}
.pushmenu-left.pushmenu-open {
    left: 0;
}
.pushmenu-push {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    position: relative;
    left: 0;
}
.pushmenu-push-toright {
    left: 240px;
}
 .pushmenu, .pushmenu-push {
    -webkit-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.3s ease;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}
nav-list.active {
    background-position: -33px top;
}
```

Apologies, I know I've supplied too much

Thanks

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: $nav_list not defined
$menuLeft not defined

Comment: Give us HTML code, not only jQuery, then we can help you

Comment: Well `$nav_list` and `$menuLeft` are, in fact, not defined. You're treating them as implicit globals which is not allowed in strict mode.

Answer (score 2):

You are using strict mode. You can't create a global variable just by assigning a value to it.

You must declare it with `var`. Since you don't need global scope for your variables, just prefix your existing lines with `var`.

Comment: I've just added those prefixes which has removed the errors, however the menu still refuses to slide when clicked

Comment: Well, that's a different problem, and probably one related to the CSS you haven't shown us.

Comment: What part of the CSS would you like me to provide?
Apologies for my lack of knowledge

Comment: The part that should cause the effect you want to happen to happen. http://sscce.org/